# Extended ascii characters search in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, extended-ascii

I have a table where one column may contain data which includes extended
ASCII characters (like `♥,♦,♣....`)

When I search for the same using `select` query the result set doesn't fetch exactly
for ex:

```
create table testasci(id int,name varchar(20))

insert into testasci values(1, 'santosh');
insert into testasci values(2, 'santosh♥');
insert into testasci values(3, 'santosh♦');
insert into testasci values(4, 'santosh2');
insert into testasci values(5, 'santoshσ');
insert into testasci values(6, 'santosh3');
```

When I search for any name with extended ASCII character like the following

```
select * from testasci where name = 'santosh♥'
```

result set displays id2, id3.

That too with question mark (`?`) symbol instead of the original character.

Any help? My result set should display only `id2` for the above search query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the characters you are entering are NOT in the ASCII range at all.  `VARCHAR(20)` is the **wrong** column datatype for your data.

1. Change your table structure
2. Change the way you insert
3. Finally, change the way you SELECT

Fixed:

```
create table testasci(id int,name nvarchar(20))

insert into testasci values(1,N'santosh');
insert into testasci values(2,N'santosh♥');
insert into testasci values(3,N'santosh♦');
insert into testasci values(4,N'santosh2');
insert into testasci values(5,N'santoshσ');
insert into testasci values(6,N'santosh3');

select * from testasci where name like N'santosh♥';
```

Looking at your original definition of `varchar(20)`, I have created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a65c/8/0) to show the problem.

```
select id, a.name, number, ascii(substring(a.name,number,1))
from testasci a
join master..spt_values v
  on v.number between 1 and len(a.name) and type='P'
where a.id in (2,3)
order by id, number
```

You'll notice that the 8th position of each of ID 2 and 3 contain the ASCII character (63), which is the literal question mark (`?`), not your special Unicode character.  So you have lost it as soon as it hit the table column.

Answer (score 3):

**`N`** is used for search extended ascii characters

```
select * from testasci where name like  N'santosh♥'
```

Comment: Now my frontend is sending ♥ symbol in url encode format.So this ♥ shape comes to sql as %e2%99%a5.Now my sql search will have this encoded value to search for ♥.Can i decode this string(%e2%99%a5) back to ♥ and search or any other way?Plz Help

Comment: if you are using C# ,use system.text.encoding.ascii

Comment: If i use System.text.encoding.ascii in c# i can convert ♥ to %e2%99%a5 and vice versa. But how i can tell SQL to search for ♥ when my search string is %e2%99%a5,as iam going to pass this string only as my search parameter.(select * from table where name='%e2%99%a5')