# Searching for extended ascii in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asciiencoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extended ascii characters search in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972174/extended-ascii-characters-search-in-sql-server)

I have table in SQL Server where data may be stored with extended charcaters (`♥,♣,♦...`) in one of the column.

From my .net database layer, the string is passed in encoded format to the database.

There is column `Name` in the DB and has value `santosh♥`.

Now from my .net code, I will pass `'santosh♥'` as '%E2%99%A5' (encoded value for `santosh♥`).
So now DB has to search for `santosh♥` in the column `Name` by using `'%E2%99%A5'` string.

For ex:

```
select * from table where Name='%E2%99%A5';
```

but the above query doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Is there anyway where i can convert 'santosh♥' to '%E2%99%A5' and vice versa in DB.My question here is to pass the value as it is and interchange in DB.

Comment: Why are you even encoding this value at all? Just create an ADO.NET query that takes a **parameter** of `SqlDbType.NVarChar` and you're done. You're overthinking and over-engineering the solution to this problem.... unfortunately, you didn't show us your **C# code** to start this search....

Comment: I cant change the datatype now.The column value is varchar and it will be varchar only.So is there a possibility of keeping the datatype same and search by encoding/decoding the value at DB level.

Comment: Yes, the **parameter** for your query must be `SqlDbType.NVarChar` (not the database column per se)